# Javascript - Split and join - Remove first 3 array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Link - split and remove first 3 array.

offerlink variable will have multiple urls. But, /content/revamp/en will remain same for all links. Have to remove this from the path name.

offerlink2 - works as expected. But, offerLink1 also getting result by excluding /hotels/india. this is required for this url.

Same code have to work for both offerlInk1 and offerLink2.

**JS:**

```
    var offerlink = /content/revamp/en/hotels/india/offers/purchase.html
    var offerLinkSplit = $offerLink.replace(/\.\w+$/, '').split('/');
    var offerLinkTrim = $offerLinkSplit.slice(-2).join('/');
```

getting output (Wrong) = /offers/purchase

Needed output = /hotels/india/offers/purchase

---

If below link means /content/revamp/en/offers/quick-deal.html

correct output = /offers/quick-deal

Answer (score 2):

Try using `slice(4)` to extract past the 4th `/` in your input:

```js
var $offerLink1 = '/content/revamp/en/hotels/india/offers/purchase.html'
var offerLinkSplit1 = $offerLink1.replace(/\.\w+$/, '').split('/');
var offerLinkTrim1 = '/' + offerLinkSplit1.slice(4).join('/');
console.log(offerLinkTrim1);
```

Note that strings need to be enclosed in delimiters, and you need to use consistent variable names.

A regular expression alone might be better here, though: match 3 repetitions of `/<anything but />`, and replace with the empty string:

```js
var $offerLink1 = '/content/revamp/en/hotels/india/offers/purchase.html';
var $offerLink2 = '/content/revamp/en/offers/quick-deal.html';
const re = /(?:\/[^/]+){3}/;
console.log(
  $offerLink1.replace(re, ''),
  $offerLink2.replace(re, '')
);
```

Comment: Sorry..not sure offerlInk2 will work with this code.. I will use same variable name for both offerLink1 and offerLink2

Answer (score 1):

```
var offerlink = /content/revamp/en/hotels/india/offers/purchase.html
var offerLinkSplit = $offerLink.replace(/\.\w+$/, '').split('/');
var offerLinkSplitLength = offerLinkSplit.length;
var offerLinkTrim = offerLinkSplit.slice(4,offerLinkSplitLength).join('/');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

If `/content/revamp/en` always remains the same, simply take the substring

```js
var offerlink1 = '/content/revamp/en/hotels/india/offers/purchase.html';
var removeText = '/content/revamp/en';
console.log(offerlink1.substring(removeText.length))
```

Comment: While not wrong, I dont think recommending hardcoded solutions is the way to go :)

Comment: Sometimes "en" "zh" "ja" "id" "fr"

Comment: changed it @Martijn

Answer (score 0):

`slice(-2)` only takes the **last 2** elements.

To remove the first three use `slice(3)`.

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for more information.